# ObjectInputStream with nested objects not reading everything

Tags: java, android

In my app I'm writing/reading an `arrayList` of objects that contain objects within them as well. (A list of `BingoPages` that contain `BingoCells`, both of which implement Serializable). The log works fine when printing values inside one of the `BingoPages` objects in the list, but when I call a method that deals with the inner `BingoCells` I get a null pointer exception. Any help greatly appreciated, been trying to get this save/load to work for too long!

My `saveAll()` method to save the data contains the following code:

```
String fileName = "bingoPages";
FileOutputStream outputStream;
try
{
    outputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
    oos.writeObject(allSheets);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
}
```

And my `readAll()` to load the data contains the following:

```
try
{
    FileInputStream in = openFileInput("bingoPages");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(in);
    allSheets = (ArrayList<BingoPage>)ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    allSheets = new ArrayList<BingoPage>();
}
```

Edit: Adding the code for the classes I am saving.

The simple `BingoCell` is as follows:

```
public class BingoCell implements Serializable{
public int num;
public int called;

public BingoCell(int id)
{
    num = id;
    called = 0;
}
}
```

And the `BingoPage` class:

> public class BingoPage implements Serializable{

```
public int pageID;
public BingoCell[][] table;
public int index;
public String winnerLocation;


public BingoPage(int id)
{
    table = new BingoCell[5][5];
    pageID = id;
    winnerLocation = null;

    //the free space
    table[2][2] = new BingoCell(999);
    table[2][2].called = 1;
}



public void insertNum(int num, int column, int row)
{
    table[row][column] = new BingoCell(num);

}
public String stringMe()
{
    StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();


        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                test.append(table[i][j].num);
                test.append(" | ");
            }
            test.append("\n\r");
        }


    return test.toString();
}
public void markNum(int markNum, int idx)
{
    index = idx;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if(table[i][j].num == markNum)
            {
                table[i][j].called = 1;

                checkForBingo();
            }
        }
    }
}


private void checkForBingo()
{
    testRows();
    testColumns();
    testDiagonals();

}

private void testRows()
{
    int hasBingo = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        hasBingo = 1;

        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if(table[i][j].called == 0)
            {
                hasBingo = 0;
                break; //Skip to the next column
            }
        }
        if(hasBingo == 1)
        {
            //Alert that bingo on row i+1 if page pageID
            alertWinner("Column " + (i+1));
        }
    }
}
private void testColumns()
{
    int hasBingo = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        hasBingo = 1;

        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if(table[j][i].called == 0)
            {
                hasBingo = 0;
                break; //row
            }
        }
        if(hasBingo == 1)
        {
            //Alert that bingo on row i+1 if page pageID
            alertWinner("Row " + (i+1));
        }
    }
}

private void testDiagonals()
{
    if(table[0][0].called == 1 && table[1][1].called == 1 && table[2][2].called == 1
            && table[3][3].called == 1 && table[4][4].called == 1)
    {
        //Top left->bottom right bingo!
        alertWinner("Top left->bottom right diagonal");
    }

    else if(table[0][4].called == 1 && table[1][3].called == 1 && table[2][2].called == 1
            && table[3][1].called == 1 && table[4][0].called == 1)
    {
        //Top right->bottom left bingo!
        alertWinner("Top right->bottom left diagonal");
    }
}

private void alertWinner(String location)
{

winnerLocation = new String(pageID + " at " + index + " sheets from bottom; location: " + location);
}

public void clear()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            table[i][j].called = 0;
        }
    }
    winnerLocation = null;
}
```

Comment: Please post the `BingoPage` class and the class(es) of anything which turns up missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    allSheets = new ArrayList<BingoPage>();
}
```

The problem is surely here. Handling an exception by ignoring it and creating a dummy object instead is no way to debug your code, or even to write it in the first place. You should print the stack trace at this point and *fix* whatever the problem is.

Comment: I had added this for when the user first runs the app there won't be a save file, and so I create a new arrayList when loading fails.

Comment: That accounts for `FileNotFoundException.` Do you really want to do that on an `EOFException,` `IOException`, `ClassNotFoundException,` `InvalidClassException,`, `RuntimeException,` ... ?